# Tool to create a python GUI for graph construction

Tags: python, user-interface, graph

I need to create a GUI for graph construction ("graph" as an abstract representation of a set of objects, not a visual representation of data). The interface will provide a choice of ~5 vertex types and of ~5 edge types. Each vertex will have two data fields: a text label and a file name, which need to be easily editable.

I'm familiar with [igraph](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) and have a lot of code written in it. I will use igraph to manipulate the graphs created with this GUI.

Since this will be my first GUI, I'm completely ignorant of what tools are available. Can you please suggest a free library, knowing that eventually the program will need to work on Windows?

## EDIT

it seems from the answers I get that I wasn't clear enough. I'm not looking for a way to visualize a graph, but rather for a way to **visually** create one. By visually, I mean not needing to manually create text files or writing code.

Comment: PyQt has everything you may want. And you can combine it with other things like matplotlib

Comment: If you can do with a separate program, you can use yEd to create the graph.  It supports exporting in formats that igraph can import, and can also handle different vertex and edge types.  http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html Unfortunately I can't suggest a reusable python library that provides what you're looking for.

Comment: Hehe, @Szabolcs. This is exactly what I do now: using yEd. However, at this point of my project using a 3-rd party tool becomes inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use python, I think [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) is a good selection.
What you have to install is listed below:

1. install Python from [here](http://python.org/download/)
2. install PyQt4 from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download)

But it takes many lines to write GUI application,
it is sometimes better to generate an image to display with image viewer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your comment on writing GUI apps. I'm not looking for a way to display a graph, but for a way to conveniently create one.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [xdot.py](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/XDot).

From the homepage

> xdot.py is an interactive viewer for graphs written in Graphviz's
>   dot language.
>
> It uses internally the graphviz's xdot output format as an
>   intermediate format, and PyGTK and Cairo for rendering.
>
> xdot.py can be used either as a standalone application from
>   command line, or as a library embedded in your python application.

Comment: Can xdot.py be used to create graphs?

Comment: I have used it in combination with networkx to build graphs from text files and let the user examine the generated graphcs visually.

Answer (score 3):

I like [networkx](https://networkx.org),

```
from networkx import draw, Graph
from pylab import show

g = Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5)])
draw(g)
show()
```

which gives,

[image: Sample output from networkx]

The only quirk is the requirement for matplotlib to get builtin plotting to work.